# Does elm have a constant for infinity?

Tags: math, elm, infinity

According to this: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Basics#isNaN

Elm supports infinity and considers it a number. Right now I am using inf = 1/0 as a constant but I want to know how I can import infinity, instead of defining it.

So, does Elm have a constant for infinity and how do I import it?

Comment: What is your use case for infinity? Elm supports it as part of the float type as does Javascript, but in many cases you would be better off using a rich datatype, wouldn't you?

Comment: Implementing merge sort, need to use it in the merging function. An alternative would be useful too.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you don't need infinity (nor a maximal bound) to implement merge sort. In fact in Elm you should even be able to implement a polymorphic merge function on any two lists of comparables.

Comment: Your right, just found it here: http://elm-lang.org/examples/merge-sort
I'm still thinking imperatively but I'am curious how to access infinity nonetheless.

Comment: You can check any `Float` using function `isInfinite`. http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Basics#isInfinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you already have an answer, but here is one way to emulate inifinty using a `Maybe`

```
infinity =
    Nothing


lessThan : Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
lessThan x y =
    case y of
        Just y_ ->
            if x < y_ then
                Just x

            else
                y

        Nothing ->
            Just x
```

Comment: This is awesome, so you're using Nothing as a limit instead of Infinity but to clarify, what is Nothing? JS undefined or null? Is Nothing not equal to zero too?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to model infinity for `Int`s in Elm, I would suggest reusing `Maybe` as in the accepted answer is unclear and not a great option, rather, make a custom type for this case that is more explicit:

```
type MaybeInfiniteInt 
  = Finite Int
  | Infinite

min : Int -> MaybeInfiniteInt -> MaybeInfiniteInt
min xInt y = 
  case y of
     Finite yInt ->
        if xInt < yInt then
           Finite xInt

        else 
           y

     Infinte ->
         Finite xInt

{-| Note the argument order is designed for reading in a pipe: y |> moreThan x
-}
moreThan : Int -> MaybeInfiniteInt -> MaybeInfiniteInt
moreThan xInt y = 
  case y of
     Finite yInt ->
        yInt > xint

     Infinte ->
         True
```